# Running python and twisted on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: python, twisted

I get an error when trying to use twisted installed using pip. I'm just using the example provided on the twisted homepage:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class HelloResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_GET(self, request):
        self.numberRequests += 1
        request.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        return "I am request #" + str(self.numberRequests) + "\n"

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HelloResource()))
reactor.run()
```

The error I get is:

```
no module named twisted.internet
```

I'm not running in any virtual environment.

Comment: What's the output of pip while installing twisted?

Comment: ha! you're probably on to something. it says "unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Comment: OK, that's strange. Can you post the complete output, e.g. on http://gist.github.com

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4691850

Comment: Is this one of those cases where you have to run it in side a VS command prompt so that the environment is set.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: i tried that before but still no go

Comment: Why don't you use the [Windows installer](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads#Windows)? You need Visual Studio to compile twisted on your own.

Comment: Or install Visual C++ Express 2008, it's free. You can get it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6506) (vcsetup.exe is the correct one).